# WPF Master-Details New data disappears from datagrid

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I am working with a WPF project which in one window includes a pair of datagrids bound to an ADO dataset which includes two tables in a Master-Details relationship. The dataset is configured with the datarelation set to 'cascade'. Displaying data works fine; selecting a row in the Master grid displays the appropriate rows in the Detail grid.

However, adding a new row in the Master grid followed by one or more rows in the Detail grid then saving, results in the new Detail row(s) disappearing from the grid.

Breaking and examining the dataset in the visualiser indicates the data is correct; the PK and FK have been updated from the database correctly. Re-running the program displays the data correctly and examining the dataset appears to display identical values to the ones when the data was not displayed.
Saving using a TableAdapterManager or using separate Update calls on the tableadapters makes no difference. In fact, searching for this on the web has led me to unanswered questions that indicate the same thing happens with EF too, while doing the same thing in Winforms works correctly - so it would appear to be a WPF issue. Any ideas guys?

Code to demonstrate this, using Northwnd:

```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        MasterDetailTest.dsOrders dsOrders = ((MasterDetailTest.dsOrders)(this.FindResource("dsOrders")));
        // Load data into the table Orders. You can modify this code as needed.
        MasterDetailTest.dsOrdersTableAdapters.OrdersTableAdapter dsOrdersOrdersTableAdapter = new MasterDetailTest.dsOrdersTableAdapters.OrdersTableAdapter();
        dsOrdersOrdersTableAdapter.Fill(dsOrders.Orders);
        System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource ordersViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("ordersViewSource")));
        ordersViewSource.View.MoveCurrentToFirst();
        // Load data into the table Order_Details. You can modify this code as needed.
        MasterDetailTest.dsOrdersTableAdapters.Order_DetailsTableAdapter dsOrdersOrder_DetailsTableAdapter = new MasterDetailTest.dsOrdersTableAdapters.Order_DetailsTableAdapter();
        dsOrdersOrder_DetailsTableAdapter.Fill(dsOrders.Order_Details);
        System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource ordersOrder_DetailsViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("ordersOrder_DetailsViewSource")));
        ordersOrder_DetailsViewSource.View.MoveCurrentToFirst();
    }

    private void cmdSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MasterDetailTest.dsOrders dsOrders = ((MasterDetailTest.dsOrders)(this.FindResource("dsOrders")));
        dsOrdersTableAdapters.TableAdapterManager tam = new dsOrdersTableAdapters.TableAdapterManager();
        MasterDetailTest.dsOrdersTableAdapters.OrdersTableAdapter taOrders = new dsOrdersTableAdapters.OrdersTableAdapter();
        MasterDetailTest.dsOrdersTableAdapters.Order_DetailsTableAdapter taDetail = new dsOrdersTableAdapters.Order_DetailsTableAdapter();
        tam.OrdersTableAdapter = taOrders;
        tam.Order_DetailsTableAdapter = taDetail;
        tam.UpdateAll(dsOrders);

        //taOrders.Update(dsOrders.Orders);
        //taDetail.Update(dsOrders.Order_Details);

    }
}
```

xaml:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MasterDetailTest" x:Class="MasterDetailTest.MainWindow"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="425" Width="912" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:dsOrders x:Key="dsOrders"/>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="ordersViewSource" Source="{Binding Orders, Source={StaticResource dsOrders}}"/>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="ordersOrder_DetailsViewSource" Source="{Binding FK_Order_Details_Orders, Source={StaticResource ordersViewSource}}"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource ordersViewSource}">
    <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="309" Width="440" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
    <DataGrid x:Name="dgDetail" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="455,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="309" Width="439" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ordersOrder_DetailsViewSource}}"/>
    <Button x:Name="cmdSave" Content="Save" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="819,350,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="cmdSave_Click"/>

</Grid>
```

Comment: Delete all that code and create a proper ViewModel and use proper DataBinding, and all your problems will magically disappear.

Comment: `doing the same thing in Winforms works correctly` - forget winforms. It is a really old legacy technology that doesn't support anything. WPF is about DataBinding, not a lot of horrible hacks. Again, delete all that and use proper DataBinding.

Comment: @Highcore that's the code that's generated by VS, in my test project. It's not the code from my real project. I get the same results in both. Soon as I click 'Save' the data disappears. I'm not using Winforms - that was just a way of narrowing it down. I'm not sure what would make it 'proper' databinding.

Comment: I don't think you should use anything "generated by VS" - again, WPF is not winforms. Create a proper ViewModel and use proper DataBinding.

Comment: @HighCore I don't use anything 'generated by VS' in production but as I said I get the same results whatever I do. I used the long-winded VS-generated code in my test project to minimise the contribution my own lack of experience with WPF might be making.

Comment: then post the relevant code with the real issue as opposed to some autogenerated code that is not representative of the real code you're having problems with. WPF uses a technique called UI Virtualization to minimize the the performance impact of creating UI elements which are not currently visible on screen. This is why you need to "hold the state of data" in Data Items or ViewModels rather than in the UI itself. state data hold in UI elements is volatile and is subject to destruction by UI virtualization.

Comment: @HighCore - it's representative in so far as it's two datagrids, and a dataset holding a PK-FK datarelation, and it's databound using CollectionViewSource. The real project has a more complex UI, and a separate DAL, and the tableadapters etc are separate from the codebehind of the window. But the demo project succinctly illustrates the issue I'm having difficulty with, even if the VS-generated names are overly long